# How can I merge field sections across templates in Sitecore

Tags: templates

Let's say I have a template, *Template A*, that has a field section, *Foo Data*, that contains some fields. If I create another template, *Template B*, that inherits *Template A* and add a new field, "Bar", how can I include the new field in the *Foo Data* field section from *Template A*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So long as you name the field section that contains the "Bar" field on *Template B* the same as you named the field section on *Template A*, *Foo Data*, the two field sections will merge.

**Example:**

Template Definitions:

```
Template A
  Foo Data
    Baz           - Single-Line Text
    Baz Thumbnail - Image

Template B
  Foo Data
    Bar           - Single-Line Text
```

will result in a display like the following on your item instances of the *Template B* template, in the Content Editor:

```
-----------------------------------
Foo Data                         v
-----------------------------------

Baz
[SLT Field]

Baz Thumbnail
[Image Field]

Bar
[SLT Field]
```

Comment: Great answer @ZacharyKniebel!  I would go just one step further (if it were me) and also explain how this design pattern can also lend itself to a duplicate field flaw. =)